# Do all the cells in a recurrent neural network share learned parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Most descriptions of modern RNNs present a "folded" characterisation, that is to say, a single cell with a loop back to itself transmitting the hidden state from one step to the next. However, in implementations the RNN is computed "unfolded", so a new cell is created for every step of the sequence up to some maximum sequence length, and the state is passed from one cell to the next.

My question is: are the learned parameters shared between all the cells in the unfolded sequence? E.g. in the case of a stack of LSTMs, does each LSTM have its own set of forget, input-gate, candidate and output parameters, or does the whole stack share and update a common set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the copies of a cell in an unfolded version share their learning parameters.

Why is it done this way? If the sequence processed by the LSTM is always the same lenght, we could conceivably get a better result with different parameters, but there are two key caveats:

1. Shared parameters are faster to learn
2. We want to be able to process cases when the lenght of the sequence processed is not fixed!